# Should i stock "quotation_request" as a table on my DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm working on a very simple DB.

Imagine I've table customer and table seller.

The customer is able to request a quotation for some products

There will be a simple form that allow to customers to select products and submit the quotation.

Now, should I create table : "Quotation" and store all quotations (with id_quotation..etc)?

Thank you all

Comment: @PeterG. Do you have "homeworks answers" ?

Comment: Sort of, quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @PeterG. It's not really a homework I'm training myself on sql and this is sort of exercise I wanted to solve

Comment: @PeterG. Just do not know if some data should be stored on DB or not, in this case it's the : "quotation_request"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all of the business rules that govern the requirements of this database, perhaps the following design will help to answer your question and explain a few concepts in the process.

In database terms, an entity is a person, place, or thing about which we want to collect and store data.  From your description we can already see two entities: seller and customer.  This is important since the entities we identify conceptually become database tables in their own right.

The seller table should contain data applicable only to sellers. Thus, the qualities (attributes) about sellers that we want to store become columns in our seller table.  Each row (record) in the seller table represents an individual seller.  Each individual seller is uniquely identified in the seller table with a unique value stored in it's primary key column, which we can name seller_id.

A simplified version of such a table could look like this:

[image: simplified seller table]

In a similar manner, the customer table should contain data only applicable to customers.  The qualities (attributes) about customers that we wish to store become the columns in the customer table.  Each row (record) in the customer table represents an individual customer.  Each individual customer is uniquely identified in that table with a unique value in it's primary key column, which we can declare as customer_id.

A simplified version of this table:

[image: simplified customer table]

I'm guessing the business rules state that any customer is able to request any number of products, from any seller, any number of times...since surely any seller would want as many sales and customers as possible!

How can we express and record the interactions (relationship) between seller and customer?

This is done with a new kind of entity: a composite entity.  It becomes a new table, having it's own primary key, and contains seller_id and customer_id as foreign keys.  The foreign keys in this table connect (relate) the seller table to the customer table.

We can name this new table quotation (if that is your preferred name).  Each row of this table is intended to capture and record each and every individual transaction between a customer and a seller.  The columns (attributes) of this table are the data that apply to a *transaction* between a customer and seller, such as amount or date of sale.

A very simplified version of this composite entity:

[image: simplified quotation table]

Note that the foreign key values that exist in this table must already exist in their respective tables as a primary key value.  That is, a foreign key value cannot be entered into this table unless it exists already as a primary key value in it's own table.  This is important, and it is called *referential integrity* - it ensures that there is no record of a customer purchasing from a non-existent seller, etc.

In the example above we can see that Builder B requested a quotation from Acme Construction in the amount of $3500.00.  They then requested another quotation at another time for the amount of $1800.00.  What else does it reveal?  All existing customers have ordered something.  Acme Lumber has not made a sale at all (yet), etc.

A design such as this enables the database to store any number of transactions between sellers and customers.  Likewise, it supports the addition of any number of new customers and sellers, even if they have not sold or purchased anything yet.  Queries can be run that reveal which sellers have sold the most or least, and so on.

Good luck with your studies!